# Moment custom date formatting not working

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to format dates in the form "Thu, Dec 20" and have moment output "Dec 20". This is what I have:

```
moment('Thu, Dec 20', 'ddd, MMM D')
  .locale('en')
  .format('MMM D'))
```

but this gives me `InvalidDate`. I've looked through the [moment.js cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/moment) but still can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just realized that moment not only formats the date, but it also checks to make sure the date is actually a valid calendar date. Since `Thu, Dec 20` doesn't actually exist, moment is returning `InvalidDate`.

If I change it to `Fri, Dec 20`, everything works.

Comment: is there a way to have moment not validate the date? But just to return the formatted date?